# Where to put txt file in eclipse, android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is the code in which I need to access a txt file "USSTATES.txt".

```
 public int count(String filename) throws IOException {
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
```

Where should I save the file in the hard drive? I tried putting it in assets folder and the root folder of the app, but I still get the "No such file or directory" error when I run the code.

Comment: try and put that in res

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where should I save the file in the hard drive? I tried putting it in
>   assets folder and the root folder of the app, but I still get the "No
>   such file or directory" error when I run the code.

So generally you have a few options based on character of file, content of file, size of file.

- Save file into sd card
- Save file into assets folder
- Save file into raw folder

### Examples:

SD card:

```
private final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/filename.txt";
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Assets folder:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("filename.txt");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

Raw folder:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.id.filename);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
```

### Suggestions:

If your file has small size, normally save it either into assets folder or raw folder. If has bigger size for example 5-10+ MB better solution is to place it into SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your file in the assets folder

To access it you do it like that.

```
AssetManager am = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("file_name.txt");
```

Comment: context would be your activity context..you can write getApplicaitonContext().

Comment: Ok, how to open the file in this code:
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("USSTATES.txt");
*Note the InputStream in my code(given above) is a little different. How to use am.open in it's case?

Comment: i am also having the same doubt.Do u get the answer?Please help me